# Android Custom gridview changes selector on scroll

Tags: android, gridview

Hi I am working with android custom grid view.I have a custom grid item with an Image View,Text View.When I click on image view it changes its color.It works perfectly.But I have a problem

1. Image view changes state on scroll of grid view
2. when I click an image view another image view also change its state.

I used the code

```
  public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] web1;
   private final int[] Imageid; 

    public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web1 = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return web1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         final ImageView button01;
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);

        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        text.setText(web1[position]);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

        image.setBackgroundResource(Imageid[position]);
         button01 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.star);
        button01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            int button01pos = 0;
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (button01pos == 0) {
                    button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                    button01pos = 1;
                } else if (button01pos == 1) {
                    button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.startclicked);
                    button01pos = 0;
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this way...

Create another array to store the values of button01pos with initial values {0,0,0,0...};

```
     public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
     private Context mContext;
     private final String[] web1;
     private final int[] Imageid; 
     private final int[] button01pos;

    public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid, int[] button01pos ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web1 = web;
        this.button01pos=button01pos;
    }
```

then in getview() method, Add this,

```
if (button01pos[position] == 0) {
                    button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);

                } else if (button01pos == 1) {
                    button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.startclicked);

                }

button01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (button01pos[position] == 0) {
                    button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                    button01pos[position] = 1;
                } else if (button01pos[position] == 1) {
                    button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.startclicked);
                    button01pos[position] = 0;
                }
            }
        });
```